# Trying to inject singleton into Activity scope to use with Fragment

Tags: android, dagger

I'm currently creating a child graph for my activity that extends the application graph. I want to implement the use of singletons on the activity to manage a WebTask that is used by the fragment in the activity.

**Problem:**
I cannot get the singleton instance of WebTask (that was injected into HomeActivity using my ConnectionModule) into HomeFragment.

So far I have the WebTask AsyncTask working to retrieve xml from the Flickr API as follows:

-Inject GetWebTask

-execute the AsyncTask

```
public class HomeActivity extends BaseActivity {
    @Inject
    GetWebTask httpTask;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //after the super.onCreate call returns, we are guaranteed our injections are available
        //do something with injected dependencies here
        if(savedInstanceState == null){
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(android.R.id.content, HomeFragment.newInstance())
                    .commit();
        }
        //working
        httpTask.execute();
    }
}
```

This will execute the doInBackground method in GetWebTask, which returns an ArrayList of the XML content from the getXMLContent method in EndPoint. I have debugged this and the member variable mImages (ArrayList) does in fact contain the data.

**Attempt and resulting error**

Trying to use the same WebTask instance in HomeFragment is giving me a NullPointerException error. I assumed that since I injected the WebTask into the Activity and executed the method as shown above, that I would have the same instance (httpTask) of WebTask, containing it's mImages member variable. I am receiving the error on the following line:

```
public class HomeFragment extends BaseFragment{
    GridView mGridView;
    ArrayList<Image> mImages;
    GetWebTask httpTask;
    //  @Inject
    // ActivityTitleController titleController;

    public static HomeFragment newInstance(){
        return new HomeFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        <b>//Not working: NPE on httpTask instance
        mImages = httpTask.getImages();</b>
    }
```

This is what the WebTask class looks like. I am expecting to get the ArrayList of Images using the getImages method:

```
public class GetWebTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<Image>> {

    private static final String TAG = "GetWebTask";
    private WebConnection httpConnection;
    private EndPoint endPoint;
    ArrayList<Image> mImages;


    public GetWebTask(WebConnection httpConnection, EndPoint endPoint){
        this.httpConnection = httpConnection;
        this.endPoint = endPoint;
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<Image> doInBackground(Void... params){
        try{
            mImages = endPoint.getXMLContent(httpConnection);
        }catch (IOException ioe){
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to fetch URL Data: ", ioe);
            return null;
        }
        return mImages;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Image> images){
        this.mImages = images;
    }

    public ArrayList<Image> getImages(){
        return this.mImages;
    }
}
```

**Dagger Modules setup:**

My module for WebTask injects into HomeActivity, which extends BaseActivity. BaseActivity is where the objectGraph is created and the getModules() method includes both ActivityModule and ConnectionModule. Those classes can be found here:

[BaseActivity](https://github.com/futureproofd/dagger-test/blob/master/app/src/main/java/to/marcus/simple_dagger_test/BaseActivity.java)

[ActivityModule](https://github.com/futureproofd/dagger-test/blob/master/app/src/main/java/to/marcus/simple_dagger_test/modules/ActivityModule.java)

[ConnectionModule](https://github.com/futureproofd/dagger-test/blob/master/app/src/main/java/to/marcus/simple_dagger_test/modules/ConnectionModule.java)

Base application Module and class are aslo located on my [Github Project](https://github.com/futureproofd/dagger-test/tree/master/app/src/main/java/to/marcus/simple_dagger_test). I hope this question makes sense. I'm really just trying to get up to speed with dagger and dependency injection. Thanks!

Comment: You can inject task into fragment as well if it is singleton

Answer (score 0):

I think you have some errors annotating classes. Your github files are no longer available, so can't really check

To make sure GetWebTask is available for injection in other classes it's constructor should be annotated with @Inject, even if it's empty. If you provide instances of that class in a module then you will have to pass in parameter instances manually.

Also, as I see from the code, GetWebTask is not injected into HomeFragment, thus it's null and you get your exception.

I strongly recommend Jake Wharthon's talk on Dagger2 - google it, video is free.
I also have a couple articles written on Dagger2 for Android here: http://aaverin.github.io/